# Camera2 live stream example

Tags: android-camera2, image-reader

I am new to the Camera2 APIs and would like to see them in action in a project that captures live camera frames, post-processes them (ideally showing how to access the raw data buffer[] using ImageReader), and previews the post-processed data.

Are there example projects showing all these steps combined?